# Using filters in website to locate a product

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, filter

I'm developing a website in HTML, PHP, js and MySQL. In this website the customers will be able to navigate through the products that the company I work for sells. As we have several different products we need the offer to the customer the ability to filter the results (imagine an eBay website).

The website is doing good, but I'm not very experienced in website development, so I'm having trouble to handle the filters. I need to pass the arguments to an php page considering that the problem is that depending on the number of filters used by the user I'll need to pass a different number of arguments.

Consider the following sql statement as example to filter the values:

```
 SELECT p.code, 
        p.price,
        p.description  
 FROM products p  
 INNER JOIN products_filtervalues pf1  
            ON pf1.productcode = p.code 
            AND pf1.idfilter=1 
            AND pf1.idfiltervalue=45  
 INNER JOIN products_filtervalues pf2  
            ON pf2.productcode = p.code 
            AND pf2.idfilter=2 
            AND pf2.idfiltervalue=6  
 INNER JOIN products_filtervalues pf3  
            ON pf3.productcode = p.code 
            AND pf3.idfilter=4 
            AND pf3.idfiltervalue=7  
 INNER JOIN filtervalues f  
            ON p.idcategory=1 
            AND p.idsubcategory=3 
            AND pf1.idfiltervalue=f.idfiltervalue 
            AND pf1.idfilter=f.idfilter  
 LIMIT 0, 15
```

It works fine, but to make this work dinamicaly I would need to have to ability to insert multiple "inner join"s lines, because the number of inner joins will vary according to the number of filter values selected.

The website is doing good so far, all the communications between PHP and HTML using jquery are working well. So, the problem is not in communication or existing errors, I just need to know how to solve this situation.

Maybe there's a better solution for that, but I can't see this now. Can please somebody help me with that?

Comment: Why don't you use WHERE close to filter your products rather than multiple inner joins?

Comment: Have you considered client side filtering. WHat you want to do is going to become a nightmare later on.

Comment: I forgot to explain how my database is structured. For understanding I have the tables PRODUCTS P, FILTERVALUES F and PRODUCTS_FILTERVALUES PF (and others that I think aren't relevant right now), that's because the relationship between P and F is N-N, so I need an intermediary table PF that has the fields PRODUCTCODE, IDFILTERVALUE and IDFILTER. That's why I used INNER JOIN instead of WHERE.

Comment: @Namphibian how would be that? I'm sorry, but my strong skills are in C++

Comment: @math look into the jQuery library. JavaScript library that is incredibly powerful.

Comment: @Namphibian I'm doing this already, I have a felling that this will be the better solution. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

If you must work with an eav model, one solution is to construct pseudo-normalized (and virtual) pivot table and then query against that as follow:

```
 SELECT * FROM eav_hell;
 +-------+-----------+--------+
 | Owner | Attribute | value  |
 +-------+-----------+--------+
 |    10 | COLOR     | BLUE   |
 |    10 | COLOR     | GREEN  |
 |    10 | COLOR     | RED    |
 |    10 | SIZE      | BIG    |
 |    20 | COLOR     | GREEN  |
 |    20 | MEMORY    | 16G    |
 |    20 | MEMORY    | 32G    |
 |    20 | SIZE      | MEDIUM |
 |    30 | COLOR     | BLUE   |
 |    30 | COLOR     | RED    |
 |    30 | MEMORY    | 64G    |
 +-------+-----------+--------+

 SELECT * 
   FROM
      (
        SELECT owner
             , MAX(CASE WHEN attribute = 'color' THEN value END) color
             , MAX(CASE WHEN attribute = 'size' THEN value END) size
             , MAX(CASE WHEN attribute = 'memory' THEN value END) memory
          FROM eav_hell
  GROUP
            BY owner,attribute
      ) x
  WHERE color IN ('blue','green')
     OR size  IN ('small','medium');
 +-------+-------+--------+--------+
 | owner | color | size   | memory |
 +-------+-------+--------+--------+
 |    20 | GREEN | NULL   | NULL   |
 |    20 | NULL  | MEDIUM | NULL   |
 +-------+-------+--------+--------+

 Another solution, more of a quick and dirty hack, is as follows:

 SELECT *
   FROM eav_hell
  GROUP
     BY owner,attribute,value
 HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(',',attribute,value)) IN ('color,blue','size,big')
 ;
 +-------+-----------+-------+
 | Owner | Attribute | value |
 +-------+-----------+-------+
 |    10 | COLOR     | BLUE  |
 |    10 | SIZE      | BIG   |
 |    30 | COLOR     | BLUE  |
 +-------+-----------+-------+
```